# How do I hide the data in my ethereum transaction request?

Tags: ethereum

How do I hide the data in my ethereum transaction request from the miners until the transaction gets written to the blockchain?  At that point, of course, the data will be visible to everybody.  But my DAPP requires that my transaction information remain hidden until it is fully written on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if you run a block producer yourself. That way you don't need to gossip to the public transaction pool.

Some "anti-MEV" solutions like [Eden Network](https://docs.edennetwork.io/) try to solve this issue using the approach above.